# É possível usar SetOutputFilter DEFLATE sem deixar cópia em cache?

Tags: htaccess

Eu sei que o `SetOutputFilter DEFLATE` tem como função comprimir o arquivo a ser recebido pelo navegador.
Usei isso no meu .htaccess para reduzir o tempo de carregamento do arquivo dados.js

```
<FilesMatch "^(dados)\.js$">
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
FileETag None
Header unset ETag
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Expires "Fri, 22 Aug 1980 22:08:00 GMT"
</FilesMatch>
```

A primeira parte funciona o arquivo é enviado para o navegador mais rápido já no `header set cache-control no-cache` é ignorado.

Comment: Uma duvida, eu não entendi "diminuir o tempo", quando você desabilita o cache na verdade o tempo de carregamento é maior pois vai ter que baixar novamente o arquivo ao invés de usar do Cache, você quer reduzir o tempo ou quer evitar o Cache?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento quero evitar o cache, só que acrescentei SetOutputFilter DEFLATE para ficar 100/100 no PageSpeed Insights funcionou pela metade em alguns navegadores o cache não é armazenado já em outros uma copia é enviada. Então como na vida tudo é uma questão de escolha deixei sem o SetOutputFilter DEFLATE .

Comment: Entendi você se refere ao Deflate pra compactar a resposta, ainda sim isso só vai reduzir o tamanho da resposta, não significa que será mais rápido. De qualquer jeito vou testar, realmente o IE tem uns problemas com os Headers.

Answer (score 0):

Sim é possível e é exatamente da maneira como você fez. Como você testou isso? usando exatamente suas regras no meu .htaccess o bloqueio de cópia no cache funciona perfeitamente.

Veja só o resultado utilizando o código que você proveu na questão:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

As regras de `Cache-Control` estão ali nos headers exatamente como definidas no .htaccess, e o Status Code retornado é sempre `200 OK`, não importa quantos reloads na página eu faça, o que indica que o arquivo está sendo sempre servido a partir do server (você receberia um `304` em caso de cache local).

Como extra você pode dar uma olhada aqui [100% prevenção de cache para arquivos](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/using-http-headers-with-htaccess.html#100_Prevent_Files_cached), contudo a única regra adicional mostrada é a Pragma `Header set Pragma "no-cache"` que já é algo obsleto a um bom tempo e na prática não deveria mudar nada.

Comment: Realmente Header set Pragma "no-cache não se usa a muito tempo nem passa na validação W3C por isso removi essa linha das regras. Testei no IE6 que também esta obsoleto e uma cópia estava lá... eu preciso de 100% prevenção de cache usando SetOutputFilter DEFLATE. As regras do htaccess funciona perfeitamente se eu remover a linha SetOutputFilter DEFLATE porem meu arquivo demora pra carregar...